# How to fix error "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?"

Tags: c#, excel

On .Net 4.5 framework, I am trying to compile C# code containing basic excel operation with worksheet. But I am getting dynamic expression compilation error for code line :

```
workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Code Snippet pasted below

```
public void CreateSheet()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet  workSheet;
    try
    {
        workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(this.FilePath);
        workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        workSheet.Name = "Result Sheet";
        workBook.Save();
    }
```

Comment: have it copy the interop reference locally instead of embedding it, the compiletime type analysis that chooses what to embed doesn't work in most cases. Also can you include the full text of the error?

Comment: wouldn't [`workBook.Worksheets(1);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.aspx) work instead of `get_Item()`? Also, try the [`Item()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.item.aspx) member of the Worksheet's collection